# Should the value of a property be updated with a method or determined in the getter?

Tags: c#, getter

Just a quick question so as to know if there is a better practice between updating the value of a property with a method that gets called everytime the value needs to be changed or just to do it in the getter.

For instance between this:

```cs
        public double Balance { get; private set; }

        private void UpdateBalance()
        {
            if (Payments.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                Balance = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                double amountSum = 0;
                foreach (Payment payment in Payments)
                {
                    amountSum += payment.Amount;
                }
                Balance = amountSum;
            }
        }
```

And this :

```cs
        public double OtherBalance
        {
            get
            {
                if (Payments.IsNullOrEmpty())
                    return  0;
                double amountSum = 0;
                foreach (Payment payment in Payments)
                {
                    amountSum += payment.Amount;
                }
                return amountSum;
            }
        }
```

The only difference I can think of is one of performance, since in the first case the getter runs through the whole list every time we try to get the value of the property. However, you don't need to worry about calling the `Update` method every time you do a change that might impact the value of the property like in the second option. Is that difference really significant ? Beyond that, is there any reason to chose one option over another ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's the second one unless the code isn't going to be performant enough to calculate it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in first method for reading the **balance** you should call the getter again and in the second method there is no **balance** at all, personally I prefer **second method** because it's generate the value at the call time so you can be sure that it is always updated and it doesn't need to call a function and then read the value so it's **cleaner** and more **maintainable**.

Comment: Thanks, that confirms what I was thinking

Comment: My pleasure to help you

Answer (score 1):

To add to Kiani's answer, if you don't mind using Linq, you could turn your code to a one liner.

```
private double Balance=>(!Payments.Any())?0:Payments.Sum(t=>t.Amount);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, though I often try to avoid this kind of formulation since it sacrifices clarity for the sake of concision.